# Failed to create calibre library at : U/media/data/files/Biblioth/xc3\xq8que calibre

Tags: calibre

```
calibre, version 0.8.38
ERROR: Failed to create library: Failed to create calibre library at: u'/media/data/Files/Biblioth\xc3\xa8que calibre'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/main.py", line 102, in get_library_path
    os.makedirs(library_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission non accordÃ©e: '/media/data'
```

please help I cann't read my ebooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `preferences > run welcome wizard` and double check that your library location is correct.

Comment: Note that I have ubuntu 12.04 lts. I was looking for welcome wizard i don't know where. Calibre was working pretty nice for two weeks and suddently i don't know what happen. I doubt maybe the OpenGL is the problem

Comment: Thanks Cubiq Calibre was working fine for more than 3 weeks and the probem just happened this morning after activating OpenGL but  again I opened Calibre this time and it works!!! I have done nothing but it works by itself wierd! Thank you Cubiq for your help I appreciate that.